# Is there any defined programming model for 'Self-Learning' NPUs?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-architecture

Qualcomm is creating a Neuromorphic Processing Unit or an NPU called [zeroth](http://www.qualcomm.com/media/blog/2013/10/10/introducing-qualcomm-zeroth-processors-brain-inspired-computing).

IBM is also working on a brain inspired chip under Synapse program.

Standford's [Neurogrid](http://www.stanford.edu/group/brainsinsilicon/neurogrid.html) might be a similar example.

Neuromorphic systems are inherently based on mixed signal and analog chips. Considering a wide application of neuromorphic computers in the field of robotics, how must be the software applications defined and process in the computer. Do we need a specialized programming language for that?

How are such systems programmed?

Comment: [neuromorphic computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromorphic_engineering) wikipedia. the systems are more "trained" in the sense of ANNs than "programmed". there do not seem to be programming languages for these chips, there does not seem to be much standardization in this field so far. on some level they are more scientific experiments in progress. am not aware of a neuromorphic design that has accomplished significant performance on standard/benchmark ML tests.

Comment: I was directed to this site http://t.co/FTlco3OLE6 by Sir Kwabena Boahen who leads the neurogrid project at standford!

Comment: I also found http://www.research.ibm.com/software/IBMResearch/multimedia/IJCNN2013.corelet-language.pdf at the IBM SyNAPSE page but I have not really confirmed it right. I hope this could lead to light!

Comment: cybersynchronicity just ran across this related question, [what is standing in the way of SNNs used in applications](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23395/what-is-standing-in-the-way-of-pulsed-neural-networks-being-used-in-applications) / [stats.se]